# Как можно оптимизировать поиск?

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм

Нужно, чтобы сравнивало две строки - одна с них которая слово, а вторая набор символов (с лишними символами). В результате если со второй строки можно сложить первую - возвращать True, если нет - False.

```
def search(s1, s2):
    return ''.join([n for n in s2 if s2.count(n) <= s1.count(n)]) == s2
```

Вопрос, как можно оптимизировать процес поиска, если строки могут быть больше 6к символов?

Comment: судя по вашему коду `search('a', 'aa')` выдаст `False`, это правильно? Хорошо бы написать в вопросе о лишних символах во второй строке.

Answer (score 4):

`collections.Counter` поддерживает вычитание. Вычитаются значения под одинаковыми ключами (буквами), отрицательные или нулевые значения из разницы исключаются. Если после вычитания `строка - набор символов` останется пустой словарь, значит в наборе символов достаточно букв чтобы составить слово.

Сложность алгоритма линейная. Константа маленькая, так как почти весь код на `C`:

```
import collections

def search(s1, s2):
    return len(collections.Counter(s1) - collections.Counter(s2)) == 0

print(search('a', 'aa'))
print(search('aaa', 'aa'))
print(search('b', 'aa'))
```

> ```
> $ python counters.py 
> True
> False
> False
> ```

Answer (score 4):

если не использовать какие-то функции сторонних библиотек, я бы сделал бы так:

1. из второй строки сформировал бы словарь, где подсчитал бы кол-во каждого символа

   ```
    db = {}

    for letter in text_src:
        db[letter] = db.get(letter, 0) + 1
   ```

это должно занять `O(n) + O(nlog(n)) = O(nlog(n))` времени

2. пройтись символами первой строки по словарю уменьшая кол-во символов и если их станет меньше 0, то все - строка не складывается

   ```
    for letter in text_dst:
        if db[letter] == 0:
            return False
        else:
            db[letter] -= 1

    return True
   ```

тут время тоже `O(nlog(n))`

Но можно решить задачу строго за линейное время `O(n)` - для этого не нужно использовать словарь, и надо использовать таблицу символов, тогда поиск нужного символа занимает `O(1)`, т.е. максимально быстро

```
def check(text_dst, text_src):
    # сформировать таблицу кол-ва символов
    db = [0] * 256

    for letter in text_src:
        db[ord(letter)] += 1

    # проверить символы слова по таблице
    for letter in text_dst:
        index = ord(letter)

        if db[index] == 0:
            return False

        db[index] -= 1

    return True
```

Comment: Операции над словарями константные. Ваш алгоритм линейный.

Comment: Таблица годится только для latin-1. Такого ограничения не было.

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, почему только для latin-1 - если 16битный unicode, то просто таблицу размером 65000 сделать - для очень больших строк будет оправдано, но раз словари O(1), то ок

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
s1 = 'hello'
s2 = 'helol'
s3 = 'hleo'
print(Counter(s1) == Counter(s2)) # True
print(Counter(s1) == Counter(s3)) # False
```

Comment: При наличии лишних символов  дает False.
Например: 'rkqodlw', 'world'

Comment: @Nick стоит уточнять детали (можно использовать не все буквы `s2`, например)...

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
def search(s1, s2):
    if len(s2) > len(s1):
        return False
    s1 = iter(sorted(s1))
    s2 = sorted(s2)
    return all(el in s1 for el in s2)
```

Comment: ваш вариант, как и мой, впрочем, не подойдет автору. по причине  
(с)  При наличии лишних символов дает False. Например: 'rkqodlw', 'world'

Comment: @n1tr0xs у меня вывело True